# Word that means "To move speedily, yet elegantly and effortlessly".

Tags: single-word-requests

ex.

> She gave me a delicate look from across the room, and - without hesitation - ______ed through the labyrinth of guests towards me."

Comment: What comes to mind...flowed?

Comment: "Cruise" fits the bill.

Comment: Skillfully threaded

Comment: ___ gazelled   ___   :-)

Comment: It reminds me of "slithered".

Comment: Did you know, if you click on the greyed checkmark, (it's only visible to you)  not only do you award 15 points to the user who  has best answered your question. You are also awarded 2 points by the system.

Answer (score 40):

I would hesitate between

- glided ([to glide (1)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/glide), implying smoothness)
- swept ([to sweep (3,4,5)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sweep), implying speed and maybe brushing aside obstacles)
- sailed ([to sail (17, 18)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sail), implying stateliness, majesty)
- breezed ([to breeze (6)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/breeze), implying lightness and maybe inconsequence)
- navigated ([to navigate (3)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/navigate), referring to the labyrinth of guests)

All have the difficulty that as they apply to a way of moving, they are difficult to reconcile with "without hesitation, started . . ."

I would probably use ". . . without hesitation set out towards me, gliding/sweeping/navigating effortlessly through the labyrinth of guests"

Comment: +1 Oh, snap! You jumped the gun! Now I discard my answer.

Comment: Please elaborate by adding references, links and stuff, you know.

Comment: +1 because I like all these suggestions, but *glide* is a regular verb, it should be *glided*

Comment: @Mari-LouA don't know what took me, probably a dastardly backstabbing attack stemming from my native tongue (Swedish: att glida, gled)

Comment: As NVZ said, these are good, but answers on ELU require citations.

Comment: @Mari-LouA (Not a quibble, just commenting because I looked this up and found it interesting.)  As you say, the simple past of *glide* is pretty much always *glided* today, but *glid* existed in the past — OED and Merriam–Webster report that it persisted into the 20th century, and Google Ngrams finds genuine examples up till the mid 19th century: https://goo.gl/nSmBXR.  The analogous *slide*/*slid* remains strong today.

Comment: How about "glided with alacrity"?  The tendency of irregular verbs to become regular is very general- performing in Middle German uncovers many examples.  For instance, _pflegen_, to maintain or tend to, is now regular, past tense _pflegte_.  It used to be _pflac_, with the same kind of vowel change you have between "glide" and "glid".  All these parallels...

Comment: What about 'navigating lithely'? 'lithe' is the first word that came to my mind...

Comment: Oh shoot, I accidentally downvoted you on mobile. Sorry `:(`

Answer (score 20):

“**Deftly**” [moved through the room...]

> [**deft**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deft)
>
> 1. dexterous; nimble; skillful; clever:
>    *deft hands; a deft mechanic.*

Comment: In reference to my answer, deftly would be an excellent replacement for my "effortlessly": ". . . without hesitation set out towards me, deftly navigating through the labyrinth of guests"

Answer (score 7):

Slipped

> to move, flow, pass, or go smoothly or easily; glide; slide. (dictionary.com)

It's a good option for an otherwise complex path through a crowded room.

Answer (score 6):

How about **Sashay**?

> [to move, walk, or glide along casually](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sashay)

C19: from an alteration of chassé, a gliding dance step

  Though it possibly suggests a bit too much [va-va-voom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/va-va-voom) for elegance.

I would probably use 'slip' in this instance, While it is difficult to find a dictionary definition which quite sums up the usage, *[Slip through the crowd](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22slipped%20through%20the%20crowd%22)* is a common and well understood phrase.

Answer (score 4):

What about **flit**, defined by Merriam Webster as

> to move or fly quickly from one place or thing to another

dictionary.com also defines it as

> to move lightly and swiftly; fly, dart, or skim along

It has a sense of abruptness and ease

Answer (score 4):

How about "flowed"?

> "She gave me a delicate look from across the room, and - without
>   hesitation - flowed through the labyrinth of guests towards me."

Comment: This just sounds awkward to my ears. =/

Answer (score 4):

you could try a form of **swift** or prance or **deft, lilt, pounce, alight**. "*Alighted* through the labyrinth, or "moved *deftly* through the labyrinth". Or a combination of words might work; "moved through the labyrinth with *alacrity* and *grace*". In this case **alacrity** conveys dexterity and confidence and ease, so it helps give an image of moving fast and effortlessly as if practiced and perfected.

Answer (score 3):

`Glided` might be an option. 
`Coasted` is  another word that comes to mind

Comment: `coasted` would to me imply without power, relying only on an initial spurt of energy. Good word but probably not what OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for something a little more metaphorical and use ***wafted:***

> She gave me a delicate look from across the room, and — without hesitation — wafted through the labyrinth of guests towards me.

> **waft**
>
> (With reference to a scent, sound, etc.) pass or cause to pass gently through the air:
>   *the smell of stale fat wafted out from the cafe*
>
> Move with a gliding motion:
>   *models wafted down the catwalk in filmy organza skirts*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/waft)

It's possible to see how the first meaning was applied to the movement of people apparently through the air.

Comment: I'm sorry, but with respect this is an *awful* choice for the example given.  It sounds as if the woman is trailing an epic fart across the dance floor.

Comment: @Jonah I suggest you change the parties you go to!

Comment: I like `wafted` for the graceful walk, but it definitely implies neither speed nor purpose, both which seem requested by OP.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I hate to keep dog piling on you, but since you self-identify as a Brit with a keen interest in "the differences between 'British' English and American English," it's my duty as an American to inform you that you just passed up your life's most perfect opportunity to drop the line *Whoever smelt it dealt it*.

Comment: @Jonah My great grandparents version of that (in broad Lancastrian) was 'first spaker, stink maker'.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using "slid" or "weaved"; either suits the given context.

Comment: `slid` would imply a sidewards movement, slipping through the guests. `weaved` would imply a weaving movement, similar to my `navigating`. Both could be good for OP.

Answer (score 2):

While explicitly lacking the 'speedily' aspect, the other parts - as well as the meaning of the sentence in whole - could be covered by a word like:
    [**Gracefully**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/graceful)

> graceful adjective (MOVEMENT)
>
> moving in a smooth, relaxed, attractive way, or having a smooth, attractive shape:

Answer (score 1):

Nimble is a good fit to describe the movement.

> quick and light in movement; moving with ease; agile; active; rapid.

It could be combined with 'manoeuvred' perhaps?

"She gave me a delicate look from across the room, and - without hesitation - nimbly manoeuvred through the labyrinth of guests towards me."

Answer (score 1):

Given the context you provided, I'd like to offer "***[gravitated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gravitate)***".

> She gave me a delicate look from across the room, and - without hesitation - gravitated through the labyrinth of guests towards me."

Definitions:

> 1. Move towards or be attracted to a person or thing:
>      *young western Europeans will gravitate to Berlin*
> 2. *Physics* Move, or tend to move, towards a centre of gravity or **other attractive force:**
>      *the electron does not gravitate towards the nucleus*

Answer (score 0):

Try [cruise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cruise), defined by Merriam Webster as

> To move or proceed speedily, smoothly, or effortlessly

Also see [Glide](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glide), defined by Merriam Webster as

> To move smoothly, continuously, and effortlessly.

There are also synonyms like **sail** or **breeze**.

Answer (score 0):

I think Law29's answers have you covered (Personally I prefer Larry's answer as a solution to the problem, but it's not what you asked for).

How about looking for a metaphor to get the point across. For example: pirouetted.

http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/metaphor/verb_metaphor.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could say that she [**slunk**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20slink) through the labyrinth:

> **verb:** slink; slinks; past tense: slunk; past participle: slunk; gerund
>   or present participle: slinking
>
> move smoothly and quietly with gliding steps, in a stealthy or
>   sensuous manner.
>
> *"the fox came slinking through the woods"*
>
> come or go unobtrusively or furtively.
>
> *"all his so-called friends have slunk off"*
>
> **synonyms:** creep, sneak, steal, slip, slide, sidle, tiptoe, pussyfoot
>   "it's impossible to slink quietly across these squeaky floors"
>
> **noun:** slink
>
> a slinking movement or walk.
>
> *"she moved with a sensuous slink"*

Comment: This is what I was thinking, too. Particularly the sensuous or provocative connotation.

Answer (score -2):

You might also consider **loped**, to give a woodsy feel.

**Lope** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lope)

> to run in a relaxed way with long strides
>
> *"The horses loped easily across the fields."*
> *"He went loping up the hill."*
> *"The outfielder loped after the ball."*

Comment: Loping is not elegant.

Comment: Wow, I'm so glad I tried this site.

Comment: If you're looking for good information about language usage, this is a great site.  If you're looking for positive affirmation from applause for your every contribution, you might need a social media site instead.